# WordPress SQL request with data from array in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I need your help. I'm working on a small plugin for some email verifications in WordPress and now I'm struggling.

I want to get an array of ID's and I get them by following code:

```
function myFuntion () {
        global $wpdb;
        $supporterIDArray = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE value = 'true' AND field_id = 1");
    }
```

Now I get an array of an unknown number of ID's like [7, 9, 34, 53, ...]

After that I want to count how many other rows have this ID. But I don't know how to do that, the code should be like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$countSupporters = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) AS allSupporter FROM myTable WHERE value = 'true' AND field_id = '2' AND `id` = **THESE IDS FORM THE ARRAY**");
echo $countSupporters -> allSupporter; /*Number of all ROWs which have an ID which was in the array
```

I hope I explained it good enough and would be so grateful if you could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want the `IN` keyword:

```
$countSupporters = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS allSupporter
    FROM
        myTable
    WHERE
        value = 'true' AND
        field_id = '2' AND
        id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
");
```

You'll need to format your array as comma-separated list. Normally, you would use `join(',', $list)` to do this, but you'll want to watch out for SQL injections and I'm not familiar enough with the WordPress query system to know how they handle it.